# Call Sub only if a USER changes the worksheet, not VBA code

Tags: vba, excel

I have a `Worksheet_Change` event where if a cell in column F changes, a message pops up asking if the user wants to change the cell text.

Now, I have VBA code that inserts new rows and, therefore, makes changes in column F, but I don't want the message to pop up or this code to be called at all.

**Is there a way to distinguish between a user and Excel itself (VBA) making a change on the worksheet?**

Comment: Set `Application.EnableEvents=False` at the beginning of your code and `=True` at the end

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just insert the line

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

before executing your code and then (at the end) set

```
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

again to make sure that Excel reacts to `Events` on the worksheet again.

For more information read this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821508.aspx

Comment: Last comment was from a typo. Thanks! Figured it had to be something simple.

Comment: Add `Option Explicit` at the top of your Module (not Sub) to avoid typos in future :)